# Name this design pattern

Tags: templates, design-patterns, interface

While doing a study on the practical use of Inheritance concepts in C#, I encounted an interesting pattern of code. A non-generic interface`I` inherits from a generic type `I<T>` multiple times, each with a different type argument. The only reason `I` inherits from `I<T>` is for the purpose of declaring overloads, `I<T>` is never referenced anywhere in code, except for the inheritance relation. To illustrate:

```
interface Combined : Operations<Int32>, Operations<Int64>, Operations<double> {}

interface Operations<T> {
    T Add(T left, T right);
    T Multiply(T left, T right);
}
```

In practice, the `IOperations` interface has 30 methods with extensive XML documentation, so it seems logical to not want to repeat these declarations so many times. I googled for 'overload repeat design ', and 'method declaration reuse design pattern' etc but could not find any useful information.

Maybe this pattern has a more profound use in languages supporting multiple inheritance like C++, where the implementation of the operations could also be provided.

tl;dr: Can you name the design pattern in the above code example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has a name. The classic set of patterns were based largely on code in older Java and pre-standardization C++, neither of which supported parametric polymorphism (templates/generics), so patterns that require them don't really show up. As far as the GoF is concerned, that's just inheriting from three different interfaces.

It's also a little bit too ugly to qualify as a pattern. Why just those three types? Why not Int16, or Uint32? Why is the interface generic, rather than the methods?

Comment: To answer your questions: the example is just an example, more data types could be added or removed. The interface is generic instead of the methods because there is a fixed number of types that support the operations in `IOperations<T>`, and `IOperations<T>` is never referenced, only `Combined` is used. The only reason this was done is to repeat the method declarations and the XML documentation. (The class that implements `Combined` implements all of the methods separately).

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion  - could be [Adapter pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern) in the part of

> A non-generic interfaceI inherits from a generic type I multiple times, each with a different type argument. The only reason I inherits from I is for the purpose of declaring overloads

I use it with *classes* too. It helps to convert the interface of a class into another interface, that is expect. Adapter lets classes work together that couldn't otherwise because of incompatible interfaces.

To be honest in your case I don't know what concept is implemented in the non-generic Interface `I`, but I suppose that is because when calling a generic method for storing an object there are occasionally *needs to handle a specific type differently*.

Comment: It sure does look like an Adapter pattern